# How to find the files modified under a clearcase branch

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I modified and checked-in a bunch of files under my branch. Now I need to get the list of files I modified. Is there any scripts to do so?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [cleartool command `find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) should help you find any element (file) with at least one version on  a given branch.

> The following will find all the files on a branch

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(mybranch)" -print
```

See [find examples](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm#_Toc158618500) or "[Additional examples of the cleartool find command](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425)" for more examples.

---

The [OP sarath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59249/sarath) adds:

> it gives me a crippled file name with @ and other characters. Is it possible to get with normal path?

True, such a command would give you something like (as an example):

```
.\.checkstyle@@\main\MyBranch
.\.classpath@@\main\MyBranch_Int\MyBranch
.\.classycle@@\main\MyBranch_Int\MyBranch
.\.fbprefs@@\main\MyBranch_Int\MyBranch
```

To get only the path, you have two solutions:

1/ look for elements (and not versions) with the right branch:

```
cleartool find . -type f -ele "brtype(mybranch)" -print
```

(note the `-ele` replacing the `-branch`)
That would give:

```
.\.checkstyle@@
.\.classpath@@
.\.classycle@@
.\.fbprefs@@
.\.pmd@@
```

But you still have the "ugly" '`@@`'.

2/ combine the find with an exec directive which describe the element found with [`fmt_ccase` format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm):

```
cleartool find . -type f -ele "brtype(mybranch)" -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Multi-line form for readability:

```
cleartool find . -type f -ele "brtype(mybranch)" \
  -exec "cleartool descr -fmt \"%En\n\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

Please note that all "inner" double quotes need to be escaped.

The `%En` will give you the name of the element found.

```
.\.checkstyle
.\.classpath
.\.classycle
.\.fbprefs
.\.pmd
.\.project
.\.settings\dico.txt
```

Comment: it gives me a crippled file name with @ and other characters. Is it possible to get with normal path?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I find a modified files under a specified folder than a vob. e.g I need to find the modified files \vob_name\sub1\sub2 . how can I do that?

Comment: @sarat: simply replace the '`.`' in '`ct find . -type ...`' by the full path you are looking into.

Answer (score 9):

The find command is the best source.  To address the OPs concerns about getting back a "crippled" name with @@ and all of the branch and version information afterwards, the "-nxn" option can be added to not provide this info.  This is much easier that doing the element search combined with exec directive to format the output.

```
cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(mybranch)" -nxn -print
```

Answer (score 7):

The above command will give all the files modified in particular `branch(myBranch)`.
But if you want to find the files modified by particular user in particular date, you would need the following command:

```
cleartool find . -version "{created_since(28-APRIL-2011.23:00:00) \
                           && (!created_since(29-APRIl-2011.23:00:00)) \
                           && brtype(BR_test) \
                           && created_by(p723029)}" \
                 -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \nName\t\t:\040%En\nResponsible\t:\040%u\nDate\t\t:\040%d\nComment\t\t:\040%c\n %CLEARCASE_XPN%" \
                 -print >> D:\test.xls
```

(in one giant line for copy/paste purpose:)

```
cleartool find . -version "{created_since(28-APRIL-2011.23:00:00) && (!created_since(29-APRIl-2011.23:00:00))  && brtype(BR_test)  && created_by(p723029)}" -exec "cleartool describe -fmt \nName\t\t:\040%En\nResponsible\t:\040%u\nDate\t\t:\040%d\nComment\t\t:\040%c\n %CLEARCASE_XPN%" -print >> D:\test.xls
```

Comment: interesting (+1). I have tried to improve the presentation of your answer to make the different parts of your command more visible.

Answer (score 3):

try this command

```
cleartool find -avo -nxname -element '{brtype(branch_name)}' -print
```

Comment: This is the only thing on this page that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script

```
   #!/bin/sh

   display()
   {
       echo "usage: $0 branchname -v vobs"
       echo "  branchname: optional, if absent uses the current view-name"
       echo "  -v vobs: optional, if absent uses default vob list"
   }

  if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
      if [ $1 == -v ]; then
          branch=`basename $CLEARCASE_ROOT`
          VOB_LIST=${@:2:($# - 1)}

      elif [ $2 == -v ]; then
          branch=$1
          VOB_LIST=${@:3:($# - 2)}

      else
          display
         exit 1
      fi

  else
      VOB_LIST="/vobs/abc /vobs/def /vobs/ghi /vobs/jkl /vobs/mno"

      if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
         if [ $1 == -h ]; then
              display
              exit 0
          else
              branch=$1
          fi
      else
         branch=`basename $CLEARCASE_ROOT`
      fi
  fi

  echo "Searching for files of branch <$branch> in following vobs:"
  echo "$VOB_LIST"
  echo "================================================================"

  cleartool find $VOB_LIST -all -version "version(.../$branch/LATEST)" -print
```

Save this in a file named ctlsbr and use this from the vob you want to find out the list of modified files.

Thanks,
Amit