# How to use cleartool find to get files containing a specific string?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I'm trying to search all files in a given branch for a specific string. So far I have

```
cleartool find . -branch 'brtype(<branch-name>)' -print
```

This gets all the files in the current directory for branch name "branch-name".
But I want to be able to search/grep those files.
How would yo do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `-exec` directive of the [command `cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) in order to chain a `grep` command:

```
# Windows syntax 
cleartool find . -type f -branch 'brtype(MyBranch)' -exec "grep aSpecificString \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""

# Unix syntax
cleartool find . -type f -branch 'brtype(MyBranch)' -exec 'grep aSpecificString "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

Note the `-type f`, to limit the search to files (not directories).

Note also that you will get the same file multiple times, if there are several versions of that file in the branch `MyBranch`.

To limit to one file result per branch, replace `-branch` by `-ele` (for 'element')
(as I illustrated in "[How to find the files modified under a clearcase branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801562/6309)"):

```
# Unix syntax
cleartool find . -type f -ele 'brtype(MyBranch)' -exec 'grep aSpecificString "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```