# How to find list of all files modified by user in all clearcase branches?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I am new to cleartool.
I did some changes in .cs files from main latest.
I have to copy those changes in particular branch. 
I have tried this command

```
cleartool find . -all -nvisible -name "*" -version "{created_by(mayur_shingote) && created_since(01-Sep-2017)}" -print
```

Comment: What is your version of ClearCase? What is your OS? (on the client side and on the ClerCase server side)

Comment: "This command does not help me": OK, but does it return an error message, or does it return nothing? In which path do you execute that command?

Comment: I am using ClearCase 8.0 in windows 10 64 bit(client side).
There is blank(no output) for given command.

Comment: Can you try with -user (instead of created_by) as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786120/6309 ?

Comment: Or maybe the date format isn't correct? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5828325/6309

Comment: Date format is correct(dd-Mmm-yyyy).
I tried -user (instead of created_by).
It shows all files that are created by me. How could I filter only modified files?

Comment: There is no issue in date format. I have tried with dd-Mmm this date format too.

Comment: First, the - name option is likely unneeded at this point. Also be aware that. -nvisible selects ONLY versions of elements NOT visible in the current view. So, if the view sees the elements AT ALL, the find will skip those elements.  First, remove -nvisible, then remove the created_since as well and see what you get... You may also want to try describing at least one version to see what it says as well.

Comment: Any news on that question?