# List all of the branches for a specific file/directory in Clearcase

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

The command `cleartool lsvtree -s .` is close but it lists more than just branches:

```
X:\main_dev\common>cleartool lsvtree -s .
.@@\main
.@@\main\2
.@@\main\3
.@@\main\4
.@@\main\10
.@@\main\2.1.3
.@@\main\2.1.3\1
.@@\main\13
.@@\main\3.0.2
.@@\main\3.0.2\0
.@@\main\15
.@@\main\4.1.0
.@@\main\4.1.0\0
.@@\main\17
.@@\main\4.2.0
.@@\main\4.2.0\0
.@@\main\4.5.0
.@@\main\4.5.0\0
.@@\main\20
.@@\main\lib-4.6.0
.@@\main\lib-4.6.0\0
.@@\main\27
.@@\main\4.6.0
.@@\main\4.6.0\0
.@@\main\4.6.0\4.6.01
.@@\main\4.6.0\4.6.01\0
```

I want it to produce just branches, like:

```
X:\main_dev\common>cleartool lsvtree -s .
.@@\main
.@@\main\2.1.3
.@@\main\3.0.2
.@@\main\4.1.0
.@@\main\4.2.0
.@@\main\4.5.0
.@@\main\lib-4.6.0
.@@\main\4.6.0\4.6.01
```

I am guessing that the solution will involve the `cleartool find` command.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) indeed, combined with an `-exec` directive using [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) and [`-fmt_ccase`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm).

Or just lshistory with the same fmt_ccase

```
cleartool  lshistory -fmt "\tElement: %-13.13En Version: %Vn\n" util.c
Element: util.c Version: /main/rel2_bugfix/1
Element: util.c Version: /main/rel2_bugfix/0
Element: util.c Version: /main/rel2_bugfix
```

That would still include the version though: you need to post-process the result in order to get rid of the final `/x` version when it exists

Something like:

```
cleartool  lshistory -fmt "%Vn\n" util.c|sed "s,/[0-9]\+,,g"
```

The [OP Derrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345323/derrick) propose in the comments [the simpler option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419014/list-all-of-the-branches-for-a-specific-file-directory-in-clearcase/58419540?noredirect=1#comment103184006_58419540):

```
cleartool lsvtree aFile | grep -v '\[0-9]\+$'
```

> I am still looking for a deterministic (no naming assumptions) way to find all branch for a specific file/directory

Any entry in the `lsvtree` which has a '0' element in it is a branch.
`O` is the [placehoster for a new branch versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5309714/6309).
See "[Is clearcase path is a standard one — '`@@`' and string after that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424471/6309)"

Example (in a dynamic view):

```
ls .@@\main\4.6.0
0

ls .@@\main\4.6.0\0
(nothing)
```

Hence `\main\4.6.0` is a branch.

Comment: Thanks. the lsvtree seems better than lshistory since it includes only those entreis that apply to this file. Also, the sed does not eliminate the non-branch entries. Any sed that I can think of makes assumptions about non-numeric branch naming. The find solution may work but lacks details.

Comment: @Derrick lshistory also applies only to the specified file. And sed will remove indeed non-numeric branch. Do you have numeric branches?

Comment: @Derrick Example of find + describe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801562/6309. But none of the fmt_ccase option would give you the branch path only. It only gives you the full extended path name, including the final version.

Comment: Yes to the numeric branching. Also, in my case lshistory gives far more results than lsvtree:
`
>cleartool  lshistory -fmt "%Vn\n" . | wc
    568     558    7602

>cleartool lsvtree -s . | wc
     54      54     991

>
`

Comment: @Derrick 4.2.0 is not numeric, and will not be filtered out.

Comment: @Derrick Why not applying the same sed expression to lsvtree?

Comment: @Derrick What does not work? The final /xx is not removed?

Comment: Correct, the sed command does not remove the non-branch lines. However, grep -v '\\[0-9]\+$' seems to do the job.

Comment: @Derrick Great! I have included your command in the answer, for more visibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201047/discussion-between-derrick-and-vonc).