# Change mastership a branch for a branch type only

Tags: clearcase

We have two development teams, one in US (replica us) and one in Asia (replica aisa). We also have three branch type:

main, dev_us, dev_asia

And a vobs of:

```
/vobs/
     ./code1
     ./code2
```

The Asian team only work on the branch dev_asia and the /vobs/code2

Is there any way to change all files in the vobs/code2 of branch type dev_asia to replica of Asian team (replica asia)?

I know the command

```
multitool chmaster –all –long asia@/vobs/code2
```

How to make it take affect only for branch dev_asia? I don't want it take affect to the branch dev_us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One resource on that topic would be the IBM article "[Transferring mastership of a branch](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/t_transfer_branch_mship.htm)", but that applies for a single file.

So you could:

- [find all elements of a given branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786120/6309)
- transfer the branch for each elements

That would affect only the right elements.

Comment: Thank you. It's not easy to by pass the Branch Path problem, again :)

Comment: `cleartool find . -type f -branch "brtype(dev_asia)" -exec 'multitool chmaster asia $CLEARCASE_XPN'` I tried it and it works

Answer (score 0):

ClearReplica is a replacement for multisite and can replicate branches or parts of VOBs.  It might do what you need.

NOTE:  I am in no way associated with this product.  I have been looking at it as a potential solution.

Comment: thank for your advice. I tried a ClearCase command and it work. Frankly, I don't like to use ClearCase :(